# Add users from another AD to my team project

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant

I've logged in to azure portal using my work account (Azure AD) and created new vsts account and team project. I can now login to vsts using my work account and add my colleagues from the same AD to team project.

Is it possible to add users/stakeholders from another company to my team project if I don't have admin access to my company's AD?

**EDIT:**

please vote for [multi-tenant authentication in VSTS on uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19587850-multi-tenant-authentication)

---

Answer from Microsoft support:

> Any user who wants to use VSTS will have to be in that AAD. Normally they would get added as an MSA account, or an account in another AAD.

Me: I was thinking about creating my own AAD in Azure and adding users from another AAD to it, but I’m not sure whether they will still be able to log in using their corporate login and in case their account will be disabled in their AAD, it will be disabled also in my AAD.

> If it is linked to an AAD, the accounts have to be in there somehow.
>
> - If he creates his own AAD and doesn’t have admin access to the corp aad, users will be added as MSA users.
> - If he did add corp users as AAD users (not MSA users) in his AAD and they were deleted/disabled in the native AAD, they would not be
>     able to logon to his VSTS. (Same is true for MSA users, if the MSA
>     account is deleted/disabled they couldn’t logon to VSTS even though
>     they were in his AAD as #EXT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoording to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-team-members-vs) doc, no.

> **Q: Why can't some users sign in?** 
>   A: This might happen because users must sign in with Microsoft accounts unless your Visual Studio
>   Team Services account controls access with Azure Active Directory
>   (Azure AD). **If your account is connected to Azure AD, users must be
>   directory members to get access.** How do I find out if my account uses
>   Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)? 
>   **If you're an Azure AD administrator, you can add users to the directory. If you're not, work with the directory administrator to add
>   them.** Learn how to control account access with Azure AD.

Comment: Essentially, you can add them as guests if you are an admin in AAD. Then they become available in VSTS.